# Can't display any data on port 3000 of ReactJS in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, package.json, react-datepicker

So I am building a date-picker with JavaScript and ReactJS. All the files seem to be fine at a glance and the terminal is working clean on the port 3000. But, when I hit that port on the web page, nothing really appears instead of a blank page. I am not sure what the actual problem is. Below is the screenshot of the rendered web page.

[image: As you can see nothing really happen.]

Also, below is the screenshot of the developer tool.[Elements part]

[image]

And, the [Console part].

[image]

Here, is the clean project directory.[App.js]

[image]

Here is the package.json file.

[image]

Please let me know if any details more required. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to be ***rendering*** anything

Comment: Append `render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))` to your `App.js`

Comment: Also (not related to your initial problem), event handlers (like, `onChange`) are normally supposed to be *inside* your component

Comment: I would imagine the render command to be in the index.js, but it seems it has been modified as well. So most likely it is missing.